# Bottom-right align, multi-line, fixed width caption, using float-row

Tags: captions, floatrow

How can I move a fixed-width, multi-line caption to be flush, bottom-right, aligned with an image (highlighted by a red box, in the image below)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}
\setulmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{4cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{slc=off}
\usepackage{rotating}

\let\newfloat\undefined
\usepackage{floatrow}
\chapterstyle{veelo}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\floatsetup{capposition=bottom}
\captionsetup{width=4cm}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{black.png}
\caption{It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by 
the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of 
using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of 
letters.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Output, Red box shows desired location of caption]

Answer (score 2):

You just have to set the caption margins, `slc=off` isn't useful here:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}
\setulmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{4cm}{3.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\let\newfloat\undefined
\usepackage{floatrow}%
\chapterstyle{veelo}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\captionsetup{margin={\dimexpr\textwidth-4cm, 0cm}}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Piero_di_Cosimo}
  \caption{It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by
    the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of
    using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of
    letters.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! many thanks...(p.s. could not upvote due to low reputation)